# How is Mike? / How is Mike doing? / How is it going with Mike?

Tags: idiomatic-language

If you know that the person you're asking about is in a coma, which of these options would you find more appropriate:

How is Mike? / How is Mike doing? / How is it going with Mike?

And which of these:

Is Mike better? / Is Mike doing better? / Has Mike gotten better?

Answer (score 1):

They all mean ***exactly*** the same. However, I feel like "How is it going with Mike?" is a bit casual. Otherwise, the rest is all fine to use.

Comment: Except that "Has Mike got[ten] better?" would be asking whether he has recovered, not just how he is.

Answer (score 0):

In this *exact and very specfic* situation, all these sound a little odd.
Being in coma is a state of being critically ill - unconscious and unable to be wakened, often as result of significant brain injury.
So if you *know* Mike is in a coma, to ask, "How is Mike?" is a bit odd. You already know that Mike is in a pretty bad place.

In any normal context (say if Mike has been ill with covid) you could use any of these to ask if he is well again, or at least getting better.